# My laptop won't turn on

Tags: 20.04, kernel, laptop, crash, msi

I restarted my MSI Modern 15 laptop. After that, my laptop won't turn on. I see the MSI logo and text after it. I tried to restart a few times, but this is what I get:

[image: screen after restart]

Can you help me please?

Comment: Please give us some details - hardware, os, what you’ve just done that might have caused this. Did something happen before this? Have you just installed something new?